Sequelize queryInterface does not insert multiple objects
I am using Sequelize as ORM for Postgres + Node system. Last few days, I have used migrations and seeds, and it worked well. However, I was using iterative loops, and I would like to insert directly using bulkInsert for an array, but it always returns Invalid Value, but it is a default object. If I insert only one element, it works without a problem. Why this is happening?
"use strict";

/** @type {import('sequelize-cli').Migration} */
module.exports = {
  async getDataFromScraper({ filename, nEstates = 5, token = ""}) {
    const scrapper = await import(`../scrapers/${filename}.js`);
    const data = await scrapper.getData(nEstates, token);
    return data; // Returns an array of objects with title, city, status, state, type, link, shop.
  },
  async up(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    const scraperData = await Promise.all([
      this.getDataFromScraper({ filename: "foo.com" }),
    ]);
    await queryInterface.bulkInsert("estates", scraperData); // it throws a error, but scraperData[0..n] returns no issues.
  },
  async down(queryInterface, _) {
    await queryInterface.bulkDelete("bids", null, {});
    await queryInterface.bulkDelete("estates", null, {});
  },
};

"use strict";
/** @type {import('sequelize-cli').Migration} */
module.exports = {
  async up(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.createTable("types", {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      },
      description: Sequelize.STRING(30),
    });

    await queryInterface.createTable("status", {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      },
      description: Sequelize.STRING(30),
    });

    await queryInterface.createTable("estates", {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      },
      title: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
      },
      shop: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
      },
      city: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(30),
      },
      state: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(2),
      },
      link: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
      },
      status: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        references: {
          model: {
            tableName: "status",
          },
          key: "id",
        },
        defaultValue: 4,
      },
      type: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        references: {
          model: {
            tableName: "types",
          },
          key: "id",
        },
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
      },
    });
  },
  async down(queryInterface, _) {
    await queryInterface.dropTable("estates");
    await queryInterface.dropTable("types");
    await queryInterface.dropTable("status");
  },
};

ERROR: Invalid value {
  title: 'Cool thing',
  city: 'Riverside',
  status: 1,
  state: 'CA',
  type: 0,
  link: 'foo.net',
  shop: 'Nice shop'
}


Could it be either status or type has a value that does not exists as a PK on the other side (in tables status or types)?
